# Neo4j Unknown Type Error on startup

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm suddenly unable to startup my embedded Neo4j instance within Tomcat. I've narrowed it down to something with the data, since when I point it to an empty data directory the application functions normally. Is there any way to recover my data?

Here's the stacktrace I get on startup:

```
2013-04-15 22:16:12.057+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: --- INITIALIZED diagnostics END ---
2013-04-15 22:16:12.263+0000 ERROR [o.n.k.i.t.TxManager]: Unable to start TM
java.io.IOException: Unknown type: -5
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxLog.getDanglingRecords(TxLog.java:492) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxLog.recreateActiveTransactionState(TxLog.java:119) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxLog.<init>(TxLog.java:114) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.openLog(TxManager.java:730) [neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.start(TxManager.java:138) [neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:492) [neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104) [neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:258) [neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.<init>(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:150) [neo4j-ha-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory.java:47) [neo4j-ha-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:205) [neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at io.foo.socialservice.configuration.Neo4JConfig.graphDatabaseService(Neo4JConfig.java:77) [Neo4JConfig.class:na]
    at io.foo.socialservice.configuration.Neo4JConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$51b1a038.CGLIB$graphDatabaseService$1(<generated>) [spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.foo.socialservice.configuration.Neo4JConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$51b1a038$$FastClassByCGLIB$$631211a4.invoke(<generated>) [spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:285) [spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at io.foo.socialservice.configuration.Neo4JConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$51b1a038.graphDatabaseService(<generated>) [spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1029) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:891) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:834) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:353) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1029) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) [spring-web-3.2.2.BUILD-20130313.181400-102.jar:3.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) [spring-web-3.2.2.BUILD-20130313.181400-102.jar:3.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.2.BUILD-20130313.181400-102.jar:3.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791) [catalina.jar:7.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285) [catalina.jar:7.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633) [catalina.jar:7.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:968) [catalina.jar:7.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1646) [catalina.jar:7.0.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_07]
2013-04-15 22:16:12.267+0000 ERROR [o.n.k.i.t.TxManager]: TM startup failure
org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Unable to start TM
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.openLog(TxManager.java:759) [neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.start(TxManager.java:138) [neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:492) [neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104) [neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:258) [neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.<init>(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:150) [neo4j-ha-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory.java:47) [neo4j-ha-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:205) [neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at io.foo.socialservice.configuration.Neo4JConfig.graphDatabaseService(Neo4JConfig.java:77) [Neo4JConfig.class:na]
    at io.foo.socialservice.configuration.Neo4JConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$51b1a038.CGLIB$graphDatabaseService$1(<generated>) [spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.foo.socialservice.configuration.Neo4JConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$51b1a038$$FastClassByCGLIB$$631211a4.invoke(<generated>) [spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:285) [spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at io.foo.socialservice.configuration.Neo4JConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$51b1a038.graphDatabaseService(<generated>) [spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1029) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:891) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:834) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:353) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1029) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) [spring-web-3.2.2.BUILD-20130313.181400-102.jar:3.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) [spring-web-3.2.2.BUILD-20130313.181400-102.jar:3.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.2.BUILD-20130313.181400-102.jar:3.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791) [catalina.jar:7.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285) [catalina.jar:7.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633) [catalina.jar:7.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:968) [catalina.jar:7.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1646) [catalina.jar:7.0.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_07]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unknown type: -5
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxLog.getDanglingRecords(TxLog.java:492) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxLog.recreateActiveTransactionState(TxLog.java:119) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxLog.<init>(TxLog.java:114) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.openLog(TxManager.java:730) [neo4j-kernel-1.9.M05.jar:1.9.M05]
    ... 79 common frames omitted
2013-04-15 22:16:12.288+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: --- STOPPING diagnostics START ---
2013-04-15 22:16:12.288+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: High Availability diagnostics
```

Comment: could you share your `graph.db/messages.log` file somewhere?

Comment: and can you check disk space and other potential culprits?

Comment: Hi @michael, here is my messages.log file in it's entirety: https://www.dropbox.com/s/65o49nvhr5z7wwt/messages.log

I've checked disk space and it looks fine. I've also totally shut down the process and started it up again several times -- the only way it starts up is when I use an empty data folder. Thanks for taking a look!